# Unable to update schema within schema after findOne

Tags: node.js, post, mongoose

Hey guys I'm trying to update my FoodSchema which is within my restaurant schema inside my POST request Here is my schema:

```
//Create food schema 
const FoodSchema = new Schema ({
   nameOfFood: String,
   numOfVotes: Number,
});

//Create restaurant schema
const RestaurantSchema = new Schema ({
    nameOfRest: String,
    favoriteFoods:[FoodSchema],
});
```

I am trying to update the food schema in the else statement after it finds it finds the restaurant and while I am able to access the data within restdata inside the `.then` method, it does not push the new restaurant. The goal I'm trying to accomplish is that if it finds the restaurant, I update its Food Schema.

```
router.post('/votes', function(req,res)
{

    //Parse the data.
    var newString = toTitleCase(req.body.restaurant);

    Restaurant.findOne({nameOfRest:newString}).then(function(restdata)
    {

        //If can't find restaurant, redirect to vote page again.
        if(!restdata)
        {
            console.log("Undefined");
            res.redirect('/votes');
        }
        //Restaurant is found 
        //If the food can't be found create and push a new array with one vote.
        //If you can find the food, then just update and add a vote.
        else
        {

            if(restdata.favoriteFoods.length==0)
            {
                restdata.favoriteFoods.push({nameOfFood:req.body.food,numOfVotes:1});
            }
            else
            {
                restdata.favoriteFoods.numOfVotes++;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Even further I am testing this code:

```
restdata.favoriteFoods.push({nameOfFood:req.body.food,numOfVotes:1});
```

Yet when I attempt to push it, it does not work. I was thinking about using `findOneAndUpdate` yet I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do here. Any ideas?

Comment: After inserting data into `restdata` are you saving it?

Comment: No I don't need to as it is already in my database.

Comment: You don't find pushed document persisted in database. That's the problem?

Comment: Correctomundo. It doesn't persist in the database for some reason.

Comment: Yes because you're not saving it. When you `find` a document it's just found. Whatever you modify in it does not persist into database unless you `save` it.

Comment: Wouldn't I use findOneAndUpdate because save would add another instance of the restaurant?

Comment: No, `save` updates the same document that you found with `find` or `findOne`.

Comment: However, `findOneAndUpdate` is better approach as it only updates the specified fields and that too on mongo server. `find` and `save` on the other hand brings the whole document to client side (node) and replaces the whole (modified) document.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it: It's not the most efficient way but nonetheless, here it is. I used Talha's save method.

```
 //votes POST route
router.post('/votes', function(req,res)
{

    //Parse the data.
    var newString = toTitleCase(req.body.restaurant);

    Restaurant.findOne({nameOfRest:newString}).then(function(restdata)
    {

        //If can't find restaurant, redirect to vote page again.
        if(!restdata)
        {
            console.log("Undefined");
            res.redirect('/votes');
        }
        //Restaurant is found 
        //If the food can't be found create and push a new array with one vote.
        //If you can find the food, then just update and add a vote.
        else
        {
            //Parse the food string data.
            var newFoodString = toTitleCase(req.body.food); 

            //If there's no food data, initialize it. 
              if(restdata.favoriteFoods.length===0)
              {
                restdata.favoriteFoods.push({nameOfFood:newFoodString,numOfVotes:1});

                restdata.save().then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
              }
              else
              {
                var flag = false;
                for(var count = 0; count < restdata.favoriteFoods.length; count++)
                {
                    //If you can find the food. Just add a vote.
                    if(restdata.favoriteFoods[count].nameOfFood==newFoodString)
                    {
                        flag = true;

                        restdata.favoriteFoods[count].numOfVotes++;

                        restdata.save().then(function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        });

                    }

                }
                //Otherwise push it as a new food.
                if(!flag)
                {
                    restdata.favoriteFoods.push({nameOfFood:newFoodString,numOfVotes:1});

                    restdata.save().then(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                }
              }

        }
    });
});

    return router;
}
```